# What exponent should I raise $26$ to in order to equal $2^{76}$?

Tags: exponentiation, cryptography

I want to figure out how long an all-caps password needs to be to equal $2^{76}$ bits of security.

I would type this into Wolfram Alpha, but I'm not sure what function to use or if it can compute (what I think is) a number field sieve.

Any assistance in computing this would be appreciated.

Comment: $2^{76}$ bytes of security is impossibly high.  Are you sure you don't mean $76$ bytes of security, or even $76$ bits?

Comment: Yes, I meant bits.. thank you @ErickWong

Comment: No problem, but you *still* don't mean $2^{76}$ bits, I suspect.  That would require a password that might take longer to type than the age of the universe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2^{76} = 26^x$$

$\ln$ both sides:

$$76 \ln 2 = x \ln 26 \implies x = \frac{76 \ln 2}{\ln 26} \approx 16$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint :  apply log to  $26^x=2^{76}$

Answer (score 2):

Use this link to post into Wolfram Alpha:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log%5B26%2C2%5E76%5D

Comment: thanks for the wolfram link

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram understands natural language, sort of.

So type

"solve 26^x = 2^76 over the reals" and you get your answer...